# Why doesn't a vertical tangent affect the validity of the solution to a first-order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on problem #2 from [Paul's Bernoulli DE notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx). The IVP is

$$y' = 5y + {{\bf{e}}^{ - 2\,x}}{y^{ - 2}}\hspace{0.25in}y\left( 0 \right) = 2$$

And he gives the solution as

$$y\left( x \right) = {\left( {\frac{{139{{\bf{e}}^{15\,x}} - 3{{\bf{e}}^{ - 2\,x}}}}{{17}}} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

which has the following graph:

[graph of DE solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XusZU.png)

Paul says this solution is valid for all real $x$, but there is a vertical tangent line at $x = \frac{1}{17}\ln\frac{3}{139}$. This corresponds to an undefined value for $y'$ and would therefore not satisfy the IVP as stated. So, shouldn't I give the interval of validity as $x > \frac{1}{17}\ln\frac{3}{139}$?

Thank you.

Comment: In the title you wrote "asymptote" but I think you mean "tangent".

Answer (score 1):

At the point in question, $y(x)$ vanishes. Thus, the DE is satisfied since it contains a term involving the inverse square, which is infinite at $0.$

The solution is valid for all real $x.$ Suppose that was not the case, then you should only have ruled out the offending point, instead of an entire infinite interval less than the point.

PS. And, as someone has also said, the solution curve has no *asymptote* anywhere; perhaps you meant infinite slope.

Comment: Thank you. Here's what I think you're saying: According to the IVP, for $y(x)$ to be a valid solution when $x = \frac{1}{17}\ln\frac{3}{139}$, the value of $y'(x)$ at that point should be $5(0) + e^{−2(\frac{1}{17}\ln\frac{3}{139})}0^{−2} =$ undefined. The value of $y'(x)$ at this point, as you can see from the graph of $y(x)$, is also undefined. Therefore the DE is satisfied.

But what is it that enables us to say these two undefined qualities are in fact equal?

And re: your second paragraph, I was taught that the interval of validity must be _continuous_. Or is this just a scaffold?

Comment: @MaxKapur (1) I don't understand your question. What I mean is that if you plug the offending number into the solution, it pops out $0,$ so that if you now put this in the differential equation, it shows that the slope at this point is infinite; by this I mean that the slope approaches $+\infty$ as one gets nearer the offending point. Thus, even though there's no assignable numerical slope here, the slope is still well-defined here in the sense explained. It would not have been defined if the derivative does not converge as one nears $0.$ But here it does -- to $+\infty.$

Comment: As for continuity. Suppose the solution is undefined at the point in question, then it would still be continuous everywhere on the union of the two open intervals created by the point from the real line, since it has a limiting value (namely $0$) at the cut.

Comment: Your first comment answers my question. My previous understanding was that an infinite value was considered undefined. As for continuity, I have read in several places that you _can't_ use the union of several continuous intervals; you must instead select the single continuous interval containing the initial condition. This was discussed on this forum [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2600005/first-order-differential-equations-why-is-only-the-interval-of-validity-with-t?rq=1).

Comment: @MaxKapur I see. We say the expression $a/0$ has no definite value precisely because it doesn't -- simply because $0$ can have no unique inverse consistent with our other arithmetic assumptions. However, if you interpret the derivative geometrically, namely as thr slope of the tangent line to the curve (which you did), then any derivative which unambiguously evaluates to $a/0,$ with $a\neq0$ simply tells us geometrically that the tangent line to the curve is vertical, which is meaningful. As for the other point, we should note that it doesn't matter in this case. *Continued.*

Comment: However, *geometrically speaking,* which again was how you talked above, the solution would have been valid at all points on the line except the offensive one. If you're thinking strictly in terms of real-valued functions of time, however, I understand why some people might require the domain to be a unique interval. However, I must take exception even to that; I admit of solutions with singularities. There's nothing strange with a function having a singularity.

Comment: Oh, I just realised that the reason for that might be that it is an IVP, and in that context of course it wouldn't make sense to consider an interval where the initial value is not defined. Thus, it all depends on how you've been thinking of the solution. In my mind, I have tacitly been thinking only of *general* solutions, without any other conditions.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your detailed response.

Comment: @MaxKapur You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Although strictly speaking the initial condition doesn't define a unique solution beyond $x = \ln(3/139)/17$, there is a unique *continuous* solution. Which should be good enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My question isn't about whether the solution is _unique,_ but about its _interval of validity_--or are these somehow equivalent? And is a solution to a DE considered "continuous" even if its derivative--which appears in the DE--is not?

Comment: @MaxKapur, a function can be continuous at a point even it its derivative is undefined at that point. $f(x) = |x|$ is a good example.